# Format external HFS disk without ESP

Tags: macos, disk-utility, diskutil

When formatting an external disk larger than 2GB, OS X automatically creates an EFI System Partition (ESP).  For compatibility with other devices, I want to format a large disk with only one partition, and no ESP.  How can I do this in OS X Yosemite?

```
diskutil eraseDisk HFS+ 002 disk2
```

I found this [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2166/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003927-CH1-SUBSECTION5) describing Apple's partitioning policy, but it doesn't say how to avoid creating the ESP.

Edit: Forgot to mention I need to use GUID partition map for compatibility, not MBR.

Comment: What kind of disks are you talking of? The GB-sized thumb drives or rather the TB external HDDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can repartition the disk with *gpt* and format the partition with *newfs_hfs*:

Open Terminal.app and to get an overview enter:

```
diskutil list
```

Get the partition table of the disk in question (below I assume the disk to partition is disk2):

```
sudo gpt -r show disk2
```

Destroy the GUID partition table and create a new one:

```
diskutil umountDisk disk2
sudo gpt destroy disk2
sudo gpt create disk2
```

If the disk previously was formatted as a FAT volume, a new GUID partition table can't be created because the PMBR turns into an MBR (which blocks the GPT creation) and you have to overwrite it first:

```
diskutil umountDisk disk2
sudo gpt destroy disk2
diskutil umountDisk disk2
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 count=1
sudo gpt create disk2
```

Get the new partition table:

```
sudo gpt -r show disk2
```

Now create a new partition with gpt. Depending on the block size of your disk you may have to align the partition. Disks with a block size of 512 Bytes have to be aligned. On disks with a block size of 4096 Bytes you can use the first free block (block nr. 6) and the size of the free space.

Example (a 2.2 TB disk with a block size of 512 Bytes):

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34  4292870077         
  4292870111          32         Sec GPT table
  4292870143           1         Sec GPT header
```

Do the math and align your volume to 4k blocks. This means: the start block and the size is divisible through 8 (and has to fit in 4292870071 blocks in my example because the lowest recommended start block is 40). Create a new partition:

```
sudo gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 4292870064 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk2
```

*with i: index position (usually 1 for the first partition); b: start block; s: size in blocks and t: type of partition (here HFS+ = 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC).*

Example (a 6.0 TB disk with a block size of 4096 Bytes):

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2          4         Pri GPT table
          6  976746229       
  976746235          4         Sec GPT table
  976746239          1         Sec GPT header

sudo gpt add -i 1 -b 6 -s 976746229 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk2
```

Format the partition with newfs_hfs (-v *name*: name the volume; -J: journaled):

```
 sudo newfs_hfs -v test -J /dev/rdisk2s1
```

The volume will be mounted automatically. Else enter `diskutil mount disk2s1`.

---

Be warned: checking the disk with Disk Utility will yield:

> Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting...

and with `diskutil verifyDisk disk2`

> Started partition map verification on disk2
>   Checking prerequisites
>   Checking the partition list
>   Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting
>   Error: -69770: Partition map check failed because no slices were found